# Linking to libraries in gcc

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I have a collection of dynamic libraries that I want to link to in /usr/local/lib, how can I do this using gcc without setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (i have heard it is bad to do this fora number of reasons).
I have spent an hour looking at this on the internet, and fiddling with command line arguments, the only way I got it to work was using the -static -I/usr/local/lib/ flag, but this converts dynamic libraries to static libraries, and the compiler throws up some warnings.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/lib` to the loader configuration in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the system wide search directories for `ldd` (the dynamic linker) in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.  In many distributions (well, mine) there is a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory, from which the `/etc/ld.so.conf` includes all `*.conf` files.  You can add the directory directly in `ld.so.conf` or add a `.conf` file in the directory.

Of course, you'll need root access to do this.

Oh, yeah: as Ignacio says, run `ldconfig` after changing these config files.